# get_terms with more than x post count

Tags: tags, terms

Is there an argument for get_terms which I can fetch terms that only have say over 2 posts associated with it?

I have a terms page which lists all my terms for 'artists', the page is huge but a lot of these terms that only have one post so I would like to show only significant terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give:

```
$terms = get_terms("my_taxonomy");
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0 ){
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if ($term->count > 2) {
            echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

a shot. It will grab all the terms and then run a check to see if the `$term->count` is greater than 2 and if so, print out those terms.

Answer (score 2):

This does basically the same as @Zach already added, but in a more smart/unreadable way :)

```
$taxons = get_terms(
     'some_taxonomy'
    ,array(
         'hide_empty' => true // is the default
     )
);
$count = count( $taxons );
$stack = array()
if ( 0 < $count)
{
    // Catch all terms that have a count of "1"
    // As we already have excluded all with 
    // a zero count are already excluded
    $to_exclude = wp_list_filter(
         $taxons
        ,array( 'count' => 1 )
        ,'AND'
    );

    // fill our stack by filtering/diffing our 1-post taxons out
    $stack = array_diff( (array) $taxons, (array) $to_exclude )
}

echo '<pre>'.var_export( $stack, true ).'</pre>';
```

Comment: You and your damn crafty answers :)

Comment: @Zach Glad you answered - remembered me to upvote yours for "most readable" ;) - Btw: I haven't measured it, but I think with an iteration of 10k rounds involving `timer_start()/*_stop()`, yours will even be faster.

Comment: Ah nice, always good to know

Comment: Hm I'm getting this error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: @Imran I'm pretty sure the problem is the objects inside the array, but please try it again and report back. In case, I'll rework it with an `array_map` another time.

Comment: @kasier: I cant get this to work with my existing smart script which lists tags in groups :P http://pastebin.com/fp85pRGg. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Imran: You should anyway simply go with what @Zach showed you  - it's easier to read and faster.